# Facebook Graph API get total likes, including on shared posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have no problem getting the amount of likes/reactions on a post on my page, but how to get the total number of likes/reactions that the shared posts have gotten?

Do I need permissions and an access token to the sharer? In theory this data should be accessible without them though, since the data is available on business.facebook.com.

Or is this something I can't access through the Graph API?

Comment: You would need to be able to access the shared posts to begin with - which in most cases, you won't. (Any user sharing your post onto their own timeline, would need to grant your app permission to read their posts.)

Comment: So the "solution" would be to collect the data from Meta manually then? Or is there a better way to do this that I cant think of?